# How do i get the response from a post request? Restsharp

Tags: c#, python-requests, restsharp

I have tried looking for the answer but i cant find it if you can please help

```
  var options = new RestClientOptions("https://httpbin.org/#/HTTP_Methods/post_post")
       {
            ThrowOnAnyError   = true,
            Timeout = 1000
       };
       var client = new RestClient(options);
       var request = new RestRequest()
           .AddQueryParameter("foo", "bar");
```

Im using RestSharp 107.3.0 please help if you can

Comment: https://restsharp.dev/v107/#making-requests

Comment: i followed the steps but i keep getting these errors    [CS0103] The name 'cancellationToken' does not exist in the current context and [CS0246] The type or namespace name 'MyResponse' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: nvm i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use .Result which will give response from both Get and Post method in RestSharp 107.

RestClient client = new("http://baseURL");
RestRequest restRequest = new("api/test");
restRequest.AddQueryParameter("foo", "bar");
RestResponse response = client.ExecuteAsync(restRequest, Method.Post).Result;
Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
```